# Opengl Create FBO- fatal signal 11 error

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

in my android game, i want to render My scene in the FBO and a texture attached to it, and use that texture later, But When i use `glGenFramebuffers` i get this error:

```
07-30 06:17:27.839: A/libc(1338): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0xd0 in tid 1353 (GLThread 157)
```

here is my codes if needed:

`createTexture` function:

```
public int CreateTexture(int w, int h){
        int[] textureId = new int[1];
        int i;      
        i = GLES20.glGetError();
        GLES20.glGenTextures(1, textureId,0);
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId[0]);
        GLES20.glTexImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GLES20.GL_RGBA, w, h, 0, GLES20.GL_RGBA, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, null);
ijad kon vali ba hichi poresh nakon hanooz
        GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST);
        GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST);
        GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

        if(i!=0){
            Log.d("ERROR", "ERROR Happend"+i+"");
            return i;
        }

        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
        return textureId[0];
    }
```

and `onDrawFrame`:

```
public synchronized void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    if(first){
    int renderTexture;
    renderTexture = CreateTexture(128,128 );
    GLES20.glGenFramebuffers(1, FBO,0);
    GLES20.glFramebufferTexture2D(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GLES20.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, renderTexture, 0);
    first = false;
    }
    GLES20.glBindFramebuffer(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, FBO[0]);
    // Some 'global' settings.
    //gl.glEnableClientState(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_ATTRIB_ARRAY_ENABLED);
    gl.glEnableClientState(GLES10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

    gl.glVertexPointer(3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, 0, mBufVertices);
    // Enable color array.
    gl.glEnableClientState(GLES10.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
    gl.glColorPointer(4, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, 0, mBufColors);
    //inja khasiate transparent ro faAl mikonim ke betoonim too CurlPage be kaaghaz alpha bedim
    gl.glEnable(GLES20.GL_BLEND);
    gl.glBlendFunc(GLES20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GLES20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    gl.glDisable(GLES10.GL_LIGHTING);
    gl.glDisable(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    gl.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, mVerticesCountFront);
    int backStartIdx = Math.max(0, mVerticesCountFront - 2);
    //Log.d("mVerticesCountFront", ""+mVerticesCountFront+"");
    int backCount = mVerticesCountFront + mVerticesCountBack - backStartIdx;

    // Draw back facing blank vertices.
    //gl.glColor4f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f);
    gl.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, backStartIdx, backCount);

    // Disable textures and color array.
    gl.glDisableClientState(GLES10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    gl.glDisableClientState(GLES10.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

    GLES20.glBindFramebuffer(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
    gl.glDisableClientState(GLES10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
}
```

any idea of Why i get such error?

Comment: You should definitely NOT create a new framebuffer in each frame.

Comment: @BDL i changed the code As you said, see the first post, But there is still same error and problem

Comment: Is the `FBO` variable set somewhere? Something like `FBO = new int[1]`, equivalent to what you do for `textureId`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you are creating a new texture and a new FBO every time onDrawFrame(), every time your application wants to draw a frame it will allocate more memory that will end in a catastrophe.

You need to create the texture and the FBO a single time before start rendering in a function something like initFrameBuffer(GL10 gl) and keep the FBO integer generated.

then just

```
public synchronized void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
GLES20.glBindFramebuffer(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, FBO[0]);
.... Draw calls.
}
```

Comment: i changed The Code As you said (see the first post)
but still same error